# how to use qsort in C to sort struct array?

Tags: c, qsort

I have a problem in my programming, I totally have no idea why I cannot use qsort in my program to sort these struct array in an ordered way? Can some way help me? in this program, there are 4 Nodes, and the every node represent a file, the node has filename, size and filetype. I want to sort it based on filename, but I totally have no idea why qsort doesn't work at all!

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>



//int cmp(const void *a,const void*b);



typedef struct  node
{
        char filename[255];
        char filetype[255];
        long ofilesize;
        long newfilesize;
}Node;
Node Line[4];

int cmp(const void *a,const void*b)
{

    return strcmp(((Node *)a)->filename,((Node *)b)->filename);
}

int main(){
  /*  int j=0;
    for(;j<4;j++){
       Line[j]=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    }*/
    strcpy(Line[0].filename,"b.txt");
   strcpy(Line[1].filename,"c.txt");
    strcpy(Line[2].filename,"d.txt");
     strcpy(Line[3].filename,"e.txt");

    int i=0;
    for(;i<4;i++){
       strcpy(Line[i].filetype,"regular file");
       Line[i].ofilesize=i;
       Line[i].newfilesize=i;

    }    



    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
printf("File %s has type %s original size %ld new size %ld \n",Line[i].filename,Line[i].filetype,Line[i].ofilesize,Line[i].newfilesize);

    }

     qsort((void *)&Line,4,sizeof(Node),cmp);


    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
printf("File %s has type %s original size %ld new size %ld \n",Line[i].filename,Line[i].filetype,Line[i].ofilesize,Line[i].newfilesize);

    }


}
```

here is my output:

```
File b.txt has type regular file original size 0 new size 0 
File c.txt has type regular file original size 1 new size 1 
File d.txt has type regular file original size 2 new size 2 
File e.txt has type regular file original size 3 new size 3 
File b.txt has type regular file original size 0 new size 0 
File c.txt has type regular file original size 1 new size 1 
File d.txt has type regular file original size 2 new size 2 
File e.txt has type regular file original size 3 new size 3
```

Comment: As you tagged C++, would you accept a C++ sorting solution?

Comment: of course, either c or c++

Comment: define 'doesn't work at all' - show us your output.

Comment: He means your sorting pointers and not structs, So the `cmp` gets pointers to pointers.

Comment: so, I shouldn't use pointer to sort, I need to use Node line[4], and use line to sort? right?

Comment: A simple research about qsort() will give you the answers. Please at least Google it. The very first result in Google is even a tutorial about how to use qsort

Answer (score 1):

What the author of the comment that got deleted said was

```
int cmp(Node *a,Node *b) {
    return strcmp(a->filename,b->filename);
}
```

should be

```
int cmp(Node **a,Node **b) {
    return strcmp((*a)->filename,(*b)->filename);
}
```

if you want to keep your pointers.

Comment: Note: Sorry to have deleted my comment - I had a second thought about its correctness and did not have time then to re- reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to solve using C++11. Let the compiler handle the memory allocations for you, and avoid all those nasty pointers.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct Node
{
    std::string filename;
    std::string filetype;
    long ofilesize;
    long newfilesize;
};

bool CompareByFilename(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs)
{
    return lhs.filename < rhs.filename;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<Node, 4> line;
    line[0].filename = "e.txt";
    line[1].filename = "d.txt";
    line[2].filename = "c.txt";
    line[3].filename = "b.txt";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
    {
        line[i].filetype = "regular file";
        line[i].ofilesize = i;
        line[i].newfilesize = i;
    }

    std::sort(line.begin(), line.end(), CompareByFilename);
}
```

Consider using an enum for the file type, and are you sure `long` is always going to be big enough to hold the file size?

Comment: Unfortunately someone removed the C++ tag. Nice answer anyways.